# Página do facebook não abre com click - nightwatch

Tags: javascript, testes, typescript, testes-de-unidade

Olá, comecei recentemente a trabalhar com o **Nightwatch.js**.
Quero testar o click no icon do facebook.

O código é este:

```
module.exports = {
        "Facebook link" : function (browser) {
            browser
                .url(http://m.unitel.ao/fit/)
                .waitForElementVisible('.socal', 3000)
                .waitForElementPresent('.fa.fa-facebook', 15000)
                .useCss().click('.fa.fa-facebook')
                .pause(3000)
                .assert.urlContains('facebook')
                .end()}};
```

Resultado é este:

```
> Running:  Facebook link
         ? Element <.socal> was visible after 118 milliseconds. 
         ? Element <.fa.fa-facebook> was present after 21 milliseconds. 
         ? Testing if the URL contains "facebook".  - expected "facebook" but got: http: //m.unitel.ao/fit/
```

Ao correr o teste ele não abre a página do facebook.
Alguém pode ajudar e dizer o que está errado?

Comment: não desculpa, nem reparei q tinha ido com tags

Comment: Para formatar código, use o botão `{}` após selecionar o código. Não precisa de tags html.

Comment: Obrigada Diego pela dica